# How to remove Icon from dock but keep in cmd-Tab (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, interface-builder, dock

I know how to remove an application from the dock by setting the LSUIElement property in info.plist, is there anyway to hide this icon and yet still have it appear in the cmd-Tab viewer (it is a status bar application). I know that it would probably be a hack, but I would still appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The application switcher and the Dock use the same criteria to determine whether an application should appear in them. It's not really clear how you would "switch to" an application that doesn't have a window anyways.

(If your app does have some sort of a window that is transient, à la Quicksilver, you should look into using a hot key to activate it.)